# JS list with image appearing on selection

Tags: javascript, html

I took my first JS class and we need to do a list that on select makes appear images.

```
<select name="entree" id="entree" onChange="changeit(this.value)">
    <option value="hidden" selected>Choisir...</option>
    <option value="hidden2">Salade</option>
    <option value="hidden3">Escargot</option>
  </select><br /><br />
```

so far this is what I have. I need help to know what function to create to show the right image when selected. If someone chooses the value salade, a picture of a salad comes up. IF someone chooses "Choisir..." no img would be shown.

Thanks for help

Comment: Ok, can you show us what you've tried in the `changeit` function? We also need the image srcs of "Salade" and "Escargot", as well as the base html for the img.

Comment: You took your first JS class and you're already asking someone else to do your homework for you?

Comment: Give it a little more effort before asking. Challenge yourself... :)

Comment: I was sick for 3 weeks straight and I need to give this soon. So yes I am asking for help for my homework. This is my changeit function that I found on w3.  function changeit(val) {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("hidden2").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("hidden3").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(val).style.display="block";
  } I just dont understand how to make this function change the pictures.

Comment: @bourki you can edit your question instead of adding the code in the comments. But as you admitted you are asking us to do your homework for you I guess the ranking won't improve. Be prepared to explain why you are using jQuery if you do use the accepted answer though.

Comment: @bourki I notice you did not edit your question. All you did was ask for the vanilla JS solution (so you did read comments). It seems you are not willing to invest time in this yourself. Think seriously about your future in software development because you not knowing how to do something is sort of everyday life as a developer... You will need to spend lots of time investigating, testing, figuring things out with trial and error. If in your first JS class you already think this is all too much work I think you may prefer another career.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the value for your select box, on change event and change the `src` for your preview image. I guess this example helps understand and go through the problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#entree").on("change", function() {

    if ($(this).val() === "salade") {
      $("#imgselect").attr("src", "https://druxys.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/SaladThumb-GardenSalad.png");
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="entree" id="entree" onChange="changeit(this.value)">
    <option value="hidden" selected>Choisir...</option>
    <option value="salade">Salade</option>
    <option value="hidden3">Escargot</option>
  </select><br />


<img id="imgselect" src="" alt="demo" />
```

I did not notice the `changeit` function there, here is the **JAVASCRIPT** way.

```js
function changeit(option) {

  console.log(option);
  if (option === "salade")
    document.getElementById("imgselect").setAttribute("src", "https://druxys.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/SaladThumb-GardenSalad.png");

}
```

```html
<select name="entree" id="entree" onChange="changeit(this.value)">
    <option value="hidden" selected>Choisir...</option>
    <option value="salade">Salade</option>
    <option value="hidden3">Escargot</option>
  </select><br />


<img id="imgselect" src="" alt="demo" />
```

Comment: Okay that is what I needed. So I just need to add IF statements for every choice of the list ?

Comment: yup, check for the values and set the src, or keep your image names in sync with your value that would be an easier method.

Comment: Do note that you just pulled in jQuery to do this task. Being OP's first Javascript lesson I can imagine the teacher expects plain JS... and honestly jQuery is kinda overkill for this.

Comment: What would be the non-jquery way to do that ?

Comment: @StijndeWitt added the javascript solution.

Comment: Thanks for adding vanilla JS solution